# Get all nested JSON objects with GSON: Deserialization

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, gson

```
[
   {
      "account":{
         "availableBalanceInCents":0.0,
         "unitCredits":[

         ],
         "accountId":2001003318,
         "currentBalanceInCents":0.0,
         "reservations":[],
         "accountSummary":{},
         "accountHistory":{},
         "status":8
      }
   },
   {
      "account":{
         "availableBalanceInCents":0.0,
         "unitCredits":[],
         "accountId":2001003318,
         "currentBalanceInCents":0.0,
         "reservations":[],
         "accountSummary":{},
         "accountHistory":{},
         "status":8
      }
   },
   {},
   {}
]
```

I want to get list of `account` using gson deserialize. Pls help how can I ignore the empty object.

I've done something like this till now, but it returns the empty objects.

```
val balance =
                GsonBuilder()
                    .create()
                    .fromJson<ArrayList<BalanceDetail>>(
                        JSONArray(data)
                            .toString(),
                        object : TypeToken<List<BalanceDetail>>() {}.type
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wrapper:

```
data class BalanceDetailWrapper(
    @SerializedName("account") val account: BalanceDetail?
)
```

And deserialize like this:

```
val type = object : TypeToken<List<BalanceDetailWrapper>>() {}.type
val balance = GsonBuilder().create()
                .fromJson<ArrayList<BalanceDetailWrapper>>(JSONArray(data).toString(), type)
```

Comment: `val balance`  at the end will be `LIST ` of  `Account`  or just an object? I need `ArrayList`

Comment: it will be `List<BalanceDetailWrapper>`

Comment: but every time I need to do  `get(0).account` to render data or to assign it to a adapter.

Comment: Can we deserialize in a way that we can get `List<BalanceDetail>` ? that will be easy for to populate a  `RecyclerView`

Comment: Sure, you can map your data to whatever type you want, for example: `balance.mapNotNull{ it.account }`.

Another option would be to create custom `TypeAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  val balance =
        GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(
                BalanceDetail::class.java,
                object : JsonDeserializer<BalanceDetail?> {
                    override fun deserialize(
                        json: JsonElement?,
                        typeOfT: Type?,
                        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
                    ): BalanceDetail? {
                        return if (json?.asJsonObject?.entrySet()?.size == 0) {
                            null
                        } else {
                            Gson().fromJson(json, BalanceDetail::class.java)
                        }
                    }

                })
            .create()
            .fromJson<ArrayList<BalanceDetail>>(
                JSONArray(value)
                    .toString(),
                object : TypeToken<List<BalanceDetail>>() {}.type
            )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need just to filter out null elements with `List.filterNotNull()` function